# Why doesn't the SharedPreference value get retrieved in another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, sharedpreferences

I have stored a value in `Shared Preference` in a Fragment  named `CommunityFragment`. Now, I want to retrieve it into a String variable in another Activity named **Add_Task**.

The problem is that when I try to retrieve that value from the `Shared Preference` I get it as empty.

Can any one suggest me what is the problem with the code. I am posting my code below.

**CommunityFragment.java**

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
{
final SharedPreferences pref11=getActivity().getPreferences(0);
SharedPreferences.Editor edts=pref11.edit();
edts.putString("mynumber",t4);
edts.commit();
}
});

return rootView;
}
```

**Add_Task.java**

```
public class Add_task extends Activity{
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_task);
    SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
     String id = pref.getString("mynumber", "empty");
    Toast.makeText(this,""+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using preferences that are private to your activity, use global to your app preferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

or use this method:

```
activity.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and in second activity get preferences using the same name: "myprefs"

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 final SharedPreferences pref11 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyValue", 0);
```

instead of

```
 final SharedPreferences pref11=getActivity().getPreferences(0);
```

and retrieve same as

```
 final SharedPreferences pref11 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyValue", 0);
```

instead of

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in your Add_Task Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences pref11= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edts = pref11.edit();
edts.putString("mynumber",t4);
edts.commit();
```

In Add_Task.java:

```
SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
String id = pref.getString("mynumber", "empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

In **CommunityFragment.java**

```
      final SharedPreferences pref11 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Value", 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref11.edit();  
      editor.putString("mynumber",t4);  
      editor.commit();
```

In **Add_Task.java**

```
    final SharedPreferences pref11 = getSharedPreferences("Value", 0);
    String Name1 = values.getString("mynumber", null);
```

Comment: Add a description, explain what your problem is, don't just post your code.